# Action of groups on graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

Let $K$ be a simplicial graph [i.e. no loops and no double edges]. Let $G$ be a group which acts on $K$ by graph isomorphisms. Suppose that the action satisfies:

- $K$ is connected
- finite number of orbits of edges (and vertices)
- each edge stabilizer is a finite subgroup of $G$

(Dis)prove that there is just a finite number of orbits of "triangles", i.e., circuits [injective path loops] of length $3$.

PS. vertices could of course have infinite degree!

Thanks to Shaun for the advice!

The problem is false if we use $4$ circuits instead of triangles: consider the graph with vertices $x, y$ (symbols) and the integers, with edges:
$[x, n], [n, y]$ for every integer $n$ 
Let $G$ be $\mathbb{Z}$, with action $\mathbb{Z} \times K \to K$ given by $m\cdot x(y)=x(y)$ and $m\cdot n=m+n$.

This action is free on edges, with two edges orbits. But it is easy to see that there are infinite orbits of $4$ circuits!

Comment: Please show your working so far. It'll help you and encourage others to help you :)

Comment: I put your question into TeX for readability - can you check I got the action right in your example? I think that's what you meant, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: yes it is correct. Thank you!